# How do I iterate over cursor response objects from the Twitter api in NodeJS (npm Twitter module)?

Tags: node.js, twitter, pagination, cursor

I'm trying to figure out how to go about getting an array of user IDs from a specific twitter list, and automatically going to the next cursor based on a property within the TwitterAPI JSON response, which is next_cursor. docs: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members || https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring

My code:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter')
var numFromCursor = -1;

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.tw_consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: process.env.tw_consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: process.env.tw_access_token,
  access_token_secret: process.env.tw_access_token_secret
})

var cursorIterator = (twitClient, cursorObj) => {
  twitClient.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json', 
{list_id: '*insert twitter list_id*', cursor: cursorObj})
    .then((list)=>{
      console.log(list);
      cursorObj = list.next_cursor
      return list
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
}

do{         
  cursorIterator(client, numFromCursor)
}
while(numFromCursor != 0)
```

At this point the code is logging an error indicating that the params are undefined. I took a look at the Twitter npm module source code, and I couldn't see anything that would make this error occur. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a callback instead of a promise? The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter#promises) say that two conditions need to be fulfilled when using promises.

Comment: I switched to callback. It works when outside of the do/while loop (the promise version did as well), but not while inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to just manually enter the next_cursor ID for each page, as the get request is working when called from outside of the loop. This is kind of an annoying solution, but it works in this scenario as the list I'm examining has just over 100 members, and each cursor array response displays 18 user objects.